Uploaded pdf's file type didn't recognize in firebase storage .NET 8
Try to upload a generated pdf to firebase storage and it didn't show recognize file type as pdf. I used iText7 to generate the pdf. I didn't understand why.
This is the method that used to upload the pdf.
public async Task<string> UploadQRCode(Stream QRCode, string fileName) {
    try 
    {
        String nameNew = $"{fileName}";

        var task = new FirebaseStorage(_configuration["Firebase:ProjectId"], new FirebaseStorageOptions {
            ThrowOnCancel = true
        }).Child("QR Codes").Child(nameNew).PutAsync(QRCode);
    
        var downloadURL = await task;
    
        return downloadURL;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error uploading file: " + e.Message);
        throw;
    }
}

This is the method that used to generate the pdf.
public byte[] GenerateSurgicalInventoryQRCode(string categoryId, string itemId) 
{
    var url = ${_configuration["BaseURL:Frontend"]}/mlt/inventorysurgical/{categoryId}/{itemId}";
    
    QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
    QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(url, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.H);

    BitmapByteQRCode bitMap = new BitmapByteQRCode(qrCodeData);
    var QRCodeBytes = bitMap.GetGraphic(5);
    
    using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    
    var image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(QRCodeBytes));
    
    var width = image.Width;
    var height = image.Height;
    
    var pageSize = new PageSize(width, height);
    
    var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(memoryStream);
    var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
    var document = new Document(pdfDocument, pageSize);
    
    var imageData = new iText.Layout.Element.Image(iText.IO.Image.ImageDataFactory.Create(QRCodeBytes));
    
    document.Add(imageData);
    
    document.Close();
    
    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}

This is how I use those in controller
var surgicalInventoryId = _idGenerator.GenerateSurgicalInventoryId();
byte[] QRCode = _qrGenerator.GenerateSurgicalInventoryQRCode(newSurgicalItem.SurgicalCategoryID, surgicalInventoryId);

var QRurl = await _storageService.UploadQRCode(new MemoryStream(QRCode), surgicalInventoryId);

What I need is to upload a QR to the firebase as pdf and retrieve using embed in front end. But there is a issue with the uploaded file to the firebase storage. Can anyone help?
